# 2D semi-diagonal pixel offsetting

Tags: opengl, graphics, 2d, game-engine, orthographic

I'm writing a fully 2d game (top-down using a 2/1 isometric viewpoint using OpenGL with an orthographic projection) in which entities often move semi-diagonally (e.g. northeast: 2 pixels to the right and 1 pixel up).

The problem with is that if you're not using fixed increments of exactly 2 and 1 (for the northeast example) then you end up with judder. For example, if you're increment is 1.0 and 0.5 then you're really incrementing x each frame but y only every other frame - and there are even worse scenarios than this.

Is this simply an inherent limitation of 2d graphics or am I missing an obvious workaround (without moving away from orthographic)?

Comment: Can you post some code? OpenGL will happily and correctly move by fractional pixels. It sounds like there might be some rounding happening elsewhere.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with fractional pixel values or even OpenGL. An entity's pixel position (in screen space) is either (0,4) or (0,5) - there's no in-between (0, 4.5).

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I don't understand, then. You said, "For example, if you're increment is 1.0 and 0.5 then you're really incrementing x each frame but y only every other frame." But that's not correct in general (though maybe it is for your particular app?). OpenGL will definitely position things at 0.5 if you tell it to. Maybe you could clarify what you're asking, then, because it sounds like that's what you're saying?

Comment: When I mentioned the 1.0 and 0.5 increment resulting in the y pixel moving every other frame, I meant it in regards to screen space. I'm using an orthographic projection and every pixel of every sprite is getting mapped exactly 1:1 onto the screen. There's no aliasing or subpixeling to speak of.

Comment: Well, what _is_ your question actually? Either you work with full pixels, and there is no in-between, or you work with some sub-pixel precision - but which will have to be rasterized to the pixels in the end, and might make things blurry.

Comment: In my last response I said, "I'm using an orthographic projection and every pixel of every sprite is getting mapped exactly 1:1 onto the screen." which should tell you that I'm working in full pixels. And as I also mentioned, "There's no aliasing or subpixeling to speak of."

Comment: Sorry this all does not make any sense at all. You are rendering with webGL using orthogonal projection. thus you are using 3D models? Or are you rendering 2D sprites using nearest neighbor  that looks like an orthogonal projection but without any 3D meshes. To get a half pixel step you need to render at the half pixel step, be that in photoshop by hand as a sprite or using the GPU from a model, or from a image and let the hardware do the interpolation.

Comment: Originally I'd said, "I'm writing a FULLY 2d game". I continually referenced 1:1 mapping of a sprite's pixels to the actual display, and even went so far as to point out that there was, "NO aliasing or subpixeling" - all of which would lead a reasonable reader to the conclusion that obviously I'm using 2d sprites and an ortho projection. There's no such thing as a half pixel step with respect to a display's pixels, which is what I am asking about.

Comment: Yeah, once it gets to the display you can't really have half-pixels. But is the "judder" actually *that* visible? In that case, we can't really tell what's wrong without seeing your code. I wouldn't expect a 30Hz pixel-sized artifact to be noticeable.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. Moving 1 pixel along the y axis each frame while moving 1 pixel along the x axis every other frame produces judder (in and ortho projection) - which is especially apparent if your camera moves in lockstep with the sprite. My question was wether there was a workaround or some alternative way of doing this that would avoid the judder.